# Accept Payments online and store credit card info

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, credit-card

We are a UK-based business and wish to accept Credit/Debit card payments on our website. Our options are:

- PayPal
- SagePay
- (Maybe) WorldPay

We NEED to store user's credit card info (of course, NOT on ours but) on Payment Gateway's server so that user can pickup a "Saved" card for quick checkout (like Amazon does).

SagePay offers a "Token System" for this - basically the business (like us) stores tokens which as "aliases" to card info stored on SagePay's PCI/DSS compliant servers. But, this system requires us to get a merchant account and hence become PCI compliant.

**We want to use PayPal to accept payments but be able to store credit card numbers on their servers and a link/token/alias to credit card on our server**

Is it possible?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Why do you need to save the credit-card, normally pay-pal will do that for you.

Comment: will you be compliant if you save the credit card?

Answer (score 1):

With SagePay "saving credit card" can be implemented with token system.

Your customer making first payment and you send card details to sage and exchange this details on token and after that, you use this token instead credit card.

We implemented this few month ago for recurring and one click payments on our website and so far all working perfectly well

To more info check http://www.sagepay.com/token-system

Answer (score 0):

PayPal provieds an API and a sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/

As part of their API you can link tokens - although you will have to do some programming. They offer a lot of support:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

As a side note, users like to see the PayPal logo, it is super recognizable and offers that piece of mind for users.

Comment: Too broad for an answer... Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that PayPal has "recurring payments" that, along with PayPal Website Payments Pro / Express Checkout can be used with something called "REFERENCE TRANSACTIONS" that let you track credit cards (stored on PayPal's servers) with a "token".

https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments